# xml diff failure with reason ":1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found" in perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have written a piece of code where i am having trouble with XML comparison.

I have stored an xml file as reference for comparison with other generated files.
I used the XML::Diff module for

```
  my $status = "0";
  my $diff = XML::Diff->new();
  my $diffgram = $diff->compare(-old =>$file_1, -new=>$file_2 );

  if ($diffgram =~ /(xvcs:delete | xvcs:update | xvcs:insert)/) 
  {
   $status =1;
  }
  return $status;
```

I am getting the error ":1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found"
Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong or am missing something.
I checked the XML file and for me the reference file and the file i am using for comparison seem fine with regards to syntax. The files are not empty.

My knowledge of XML is limited and any pointers here will be helpful.

Regards,
KP

Comment: Just to add:I am able to open the XML files in browser and i don't see any problem there. I tried searching in Perl XML Diff module documentation but couldn't find anything to help in this regards.

Comment: Can you post some sample XML files where this error happens? The problem probably isn't with your script.

Comment: Date in the XML file is something like this....and the nested structure is even bigger than this sample .....                                                          <abc><def><ghi>sample</ghi></def></abc>                                            ...both xml files are along these lines....i don't have                                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> this at the starting of both files.

Comment: sorry Data not Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I used the Data::Dumper to check the content of xml files , converted them to data structure using XMLin() and found that one of the xml files path was not working as expected.

Thank you @AKHolland. Your comment made me look at the code which was passing the files for comparison.

Lesson Learnt: Never assume your code is the culprit always. You can be correct at times :)